# fat-free framework only working through cli

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I just started trying to use the fat-free framework. I don't understand what i am doing wrong here. I have the following code that i got from their site:

```
$f3 = require('/var/tmp/fatfree-master/lib/base.php');
$f3->route('GET /',
    function() {
        echo 'Hello, world!';
    }
);

$f3->run();
?>
```

When i run the following code using the cli, like this php index.php it works fine. But when i try to go to it with a browser i get the following error:

```
Not Found

HTTP 404 (GET /index.php)
```

I don't understand how it works through cli and not through a browser. Anyone come across this before?

Comment: Is `index.php` in your document root?

Comment: Have you setup htaccess and rewrite rules? https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree#sample-apache-configuration .. looks like it defaults to trying to find the index file for the directory instead (index.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget everything about any PHP files in your URL. You don't need them and you don't use them in any URL. So, just open `example.org/` instead of `example.org/index.php` and it will work.

Also make sure, as mentioned by Ben in the comments, to configure .htaccess properly as described here: https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree#sample-apache-configuration

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Awesome it works!! but how can i get it to work with going to index.php, only reason i am asking is because if i have a link within the site that points to that it won't work.

Comment: You could redirect via `.htaccess`. It might look like this: `Redirect /index.php /`. The other way would be, you create a new route in F3 like `$f3->route('GET /index.php', function($f3) { $f3->redirect('/'); }`. Just an example which might not work like this.

Comment: @Brad Hazelnut Think of index.php as the entry point for all requests through Fat Free.  The links on your site should reference routes that you configure such as / or /blablah but should not need to reference index.php in any way directly.  I imagine this makes sense by now :-)