# Fatfree 404 not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, fat-free-framework

Im testing fatfree. and it dont wants to run :/.

If i go to localHost/f3/ it is showing the index.php
but if i type localhost/f3/index.php it says

```
Not Found

HTTP 404 (GET /index.php)

• vev/index.php:14 Base->run()
```

So i think the mod rewrite its not working? my .htaccess is

```
 # Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /vev/index.php [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^/google http://www.google.com [L,NC];
```

I also tried to rewirte the google but also not working. i get the misconfigured error.
Also tried:

```
RewriteBase /vev/
RewirteRule .* /index.php or /vev/index.php or index.php
```

Whats wrong?!

Thanks

Comment: what is the url? you are using to call the page ..

Comment: http://localhost/f3/index.php

Comment: did you mentioned routes in index.php or in routes.ini files ?? you cant just run the above mentioned url?

Comment: is ur folder structure like f3/vev/index.php and f3/.htaccess??

Comment: Already posted the answer to a similiar question yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622192/fat-free-framework-only-working-through-cli/24631385#24631385

Comment: Sascha, if i try your htacces example posted it does not work.

Comment: it depends on your folder structure.. if it's under /f3, set RewriteBase /f3/

Comment: @user1010775 F3 throws a 404 error for any route which is undefined. So calling /index.php will always raise a 404 unless you define a route like `$f3->route('GET /index.php',function($f3){//do something})`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you want to access the page using index.php, reason of using framework route module making url's pretty. I assume you want to access the same page using multiple url's. You can do it, by doing something similar route configuration.

```
$f3->route(array('GET /','GET /index.php'),
    function($f3) { 
   //do something
})
```

Now you can access the index page using **localHost/f3/** and **localhost/f3/index.php**